# Regex of three optional parts with separators

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse the three optional components of a string with this format any of these different combinations:

```
12345,abcd@ABCD   -> $1=12345 $2=abcd $3=ABC
12345,abcd        -> $1=12345 $2=abcd $3=empty
12345@ABCD        -> $1=12345 $2=empty $3=ABC
12345             -> $1=12345 $2=emty $3=empty
```

Is it possible with a single regexp?
I have done several attempts. When the string is complete no problem but the forms with parameters missing are escaping to me:

```
(.+),(.+)@(.+)           // works when the string is complete
                         //  but how do you express the optionality?
(.+),?(.+)@?(.+)         // nope
(.*)[$,](.*)[$@](.*)     // neither
```

(Another option, would be splitting the string into the components that looks quite trivial but I am curious about the regexp way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
^([^,@]+)(?:,([^@]+))?(?:@(.+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h8Xhau/1) (note there are newlines added in the demo pattern since the test is performed against a single multiline string there, in real world, the strings to test won't contain newlines, hence they are not in the pattern here.)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([^,@]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than a comma and `@`
- `(?:,([^@]+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of a comma and then (capturing into Group 2) any one or more chars other than `@`
- `(?:@(.+))?`  - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of a `@` char and then (capturing into Group 3) any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 4):

```
12345,abcd@ABCD   -> $1=12345 $2=abcd $3=ABC
12345,abcd        -> $1=12345 $2=abcd $3=empty
12345@ABCD        -> $1=12345 $2=empty $3=ABC
12345             -> $1=12345 $2=emty $3=empty
```

From your expected output it appears that you want **empty groups** in your matches while matching your inputs. You may use this regex:

```
/^(\d+),?([^@\n]*)@?(.*)$/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vEEy3f/1)

Note that this regex will always return 3 captured groups in every match result.

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits and capture in group #1
- `,?`: Match an optional comma
- `([^@]*)`: Match 0+ any character that is not `@` and capture in group #2
- `@?`: Match an optional `@`
- `(.*)`: Match 0+ any character and capture in group #3
- `$`: End